# Android IntentService not completing task if App is closed

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-service, intentservice

I'm using an IntentService to saveData to a SQLDatabase & upload data to Parse. The IntentService works fine if I keep the app running. It also executes propery if I minimise it(by pressing the home button).

But if I press the navigation button and destory the app(the thing where the app screen scales down and you swipe it off); then the IntentService stops running(it doesnt even call onDestory).

What I want is to have the service execute all the tasks; and destory itself. Hence, START_STICKY (Intent) is not required as I dont want it to run continuously in the background.

**Starting IntentService**

```
Intent intent_publishService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PublishService.class);

Bundle basket_storyData = new Bundle();
basket_storyData.putAll( packStoryData() );
intent_publishService.putExtra(KEY_BASKET_STORY_DATA, basket_storyData);

intent_publishService.putParcelableArrayListExtra(KEY_BASKET_IMAGE_DATA, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) final_image_data);
startService(intent_publishService);
```

**PublishService.class *(Snippet)***

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "ONHANDLEINTENT" );

    context = getApplicationContext();

    final String KEY_BASKET_IMAGE_DATA = "key_basket_image_data";
    final String KEY_BASKET_STORY_DATA = "key_basket_story_data";
    final String KEY_BASKET_EXTRA      = "key_basket_extra";


    ArrayList<ImagesData> _iDataSave = new ArrayList<ImagesData>();
    _iDataSave.addAll( (Collection<? extends ImagesData>) intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(KEY_BASKET_IMAGE_DATA) );

    Log.i(TAG, "_iDataSize:" + Integer.toString(_iDataSave.size()) );

    //Get Bundle Values
    Bundle storyBundle = intent.getBundleExtra(KEY_BASKET_STORY_DATA);

    publishStory(storyBundle, _iDataSave);
}
```

**Edit1: Manifest Declaration**

```
<service android:name="com.example.create.main.PublishService" />
```

**SOLVED**

Answer (score 1):

You will need START_STICKY in this case to indicate to android that you wish to try to continue to do work after the app is killed.

When the user swipes away from the app chooser, that will kill the app process unconditionally.  You can't prevent that from happening - it is intended to give the user control over what is running at that very moment.

Comment: But 'onHandleIntent' does not have a return type; and using onStartCommand is not recommended in an IntentService.

Comment: Then you can create your own service.  It's very easy to find and copy the source to IntentService to make it do what you want.

Comment: I switched to IntentService cuz a Service runs on the main thread, while an IntentService runs on its own thread.

Comment: Yes, and you can copy IntentService and its threading strategy to make it do what you want.

Comment: So I need something like START_STICKY from Service + Running on a separate Thread from IntentService

Comment: START_STICKY recreates the service. I dont want that to happen. I just want the Service to continue doing the remaining steps uninterrupted; and then destroy itself

Comment: You can't do that in spite of the user's request to kill your app.  The user maintains ultimate control.

Comment: I just need the Service to run in the background. Anyways, Ill update the answer once its solved; you arn't helping

Comment: Check my solution out

Answer (score 1):

Here's what needs to be done:

1) Change IntentService >> Service

2) Move all the code to onStartCommand

3) Using a separate thread so that everything is done off the UI-Thread

4) Declaring it as a separate process in the Manifest

**PublishService.class *(Snippet)***

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "ONSTARTCOMMAND" );

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyFriendList_Activity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());

    builder.setAutoCancel(false);
    builder.setTicker("this is ticker text");
    builder.setContentTitle("WhatsApp Notification");               
    builder.setContentText("You have a new message");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    //builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setOngoing(true);
    builder.setNumber(100);

    // Sets the progress indicator to a max value, the current completion
    // percentage, and "determinate" state
    builder.setProgress(0, 0, true);

    Notification notificationFinal = builder.getNotification();

    startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationFinal );

    Runnable r = new Runnable() 
    {       
        public void run() 
        {
            context = getApplicationContext();

            final String KEY_BASKET_IMAGE_DATA = "key_basket_image_data";
            final String KEY_BASKET_STORY_DATA = "key_basket_story_data";
            final String KEY_BASKET_EXTRA      = "key_basket_extra";


            ArrayList<ImagesData> _iDataSave = new ArrayList<ImagesData>();
            _iDataSave.addAll( (Collection<? extends ImagesData>) intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(KEY_BASKET_IMAGE_DATA) );

            Log.i(TAG, "_iDataSize:" + Integer.toString(_iDataSave.size()) );

            //Get Bundle Values
            Bundle storyBundle = intent.getBundleExtra(KEY_BASKET_STORY_DATA);

            publishStory(storyBundle, _iDataSave);               
        }
    };

    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();

    //return START_STICKY;
    //return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    //return START_CONTINUATION_MASK;
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

**Manifest Declaration**

```
   <service
        android:name="com.example.create.main.PublishService"
        android:process=".publishservice" />
```

**Concern**

startForeground() + separate Process + running on a separate Thread

--- maybe all 3-are not required?

**Edit 1:** Also; you could skip all the foreground stuff; and return START_CONTINUATION_MASK ; but thats not recommended as every device has a different way of handling that return type

Comment: I just tested this, and it doesn't work (emulator, API level 23).  When you swipe away the app from the chooser, it kills the other process as well.  You can see it in the logcat.  The name of the app is "test.app" and the name of the process is "proc": `ActivityManager: Killing 3390:test.app:proc/u0a60 (adj 8): remove task`

Comment: Im running it on Android(5.0.2) works for me. Try running it on a device; and let me know. min14;max23.

Comment: Also; return 'START_NOT_STICKY'  & I call stopSelf() when the task is done ; so maybe run a dummy-loop and call stopSelf() after a while?

Comment: @DougStevenson are you still having the same issue on the device?

Comment: I am trying to upload video to server using retrofit by this method. After closing app notification is there but progress is stopped.